# How to store the last sum of a row in C

Tags: c

I'm doing this exercise
"take as input a matrix of n rows and m columns of natural numbers (n and m are also
acquired from input). The program check if the sum of the numbers
contained in each row is the same for all rows"

I can't figure out how to save the last sum of the rows in the matrix. If I insert a temporary variable to allocate the last sum then it is overwritten in the next for cycle

```
int main ()
{

    int i, j;
    int sum;
    int temp;
    int n=3, m=3;
    int matrix[n][m];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {       
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            printf("Enter: ");
            scanf("%d",&matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {           
        sum=0;          
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            sum+=matrix[i][j];                                              
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you print the sum of the row?

Comment: I don't see an issue with overwriting the last sum as long as it's the same, then it's not really getting overwritten is it? And when it's different then you don't have to overwrite it as that's what the program is supposed to check anyway.

Comment: @Longoon12000 How would you know it was different from the previous sum if you have already zeroed it `sum=0;` ? Better would be either a separate variable `lastsum` or an array of sums and check after filling it.

Comment: Okay I see, then it just needs a separate sum variable for the for loop that gets compared with the broad sum variable.

Comment: @Longoon12000 so i need to check if the last sum if the same of the previous one, i tried whit a if cycle but it doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping the code really similar to what you have right now you could do something like this:

```
int main (){
    int i, j;
    int sum = 0;
    int oldsum = 0;
    int temp;
    int n=3, m=3;
    int matrix[n][m];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {       
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            printf("Enter: ");
            scanf("%d",&matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {           
        sum=0;          
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            sum+=matrix[i][j];                                              
        }  
        if (i == 0 || sum == oldsum){
            oldsum = sum;
        }         
        else {
            printf("The sums are not equal!\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    printf("All the sums are equal!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Since you need to check if the sum for all rows is the same you can safely stop the program when you find a sum that is different from the previous one, in this case when you find a different sum you `return 1` otherwise you `return 0` at the end of `main`.

The `||` in the condition is used to handle the first sum calculation when both `sum` and `oldsum` are still 0;

Answer (score 0):

Add one more `int` array `Row_sum[n]`

```
   int main ()
    {

        int i, j;
        int sum;
        int temp;
        int n=3, m=3;
        int matrix[n][m];
        int Row_sum[n]

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {       
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                printf("Enter: ");
                scanf("%d",&matrix[i][j]);
            }
        }

        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        {           
            sum=0;          
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                sum+=matrix[i][j];                                              
            }
            Row_sum[i] = sum;           
        }

        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
           for(j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
           {
               if(Row_sum[i] == Row_sum[j])
               {                
                  printf("Sum of rows in matrix are equal", i, j);
               }
            }
         }

         printf("\nSum of rows in matrix are not equal", flag);
    }
```

Comment: I suggest for this specific case not to use an array as it's only required to check if any sum is different than a previous one which doesn't require storing all sums.

Comment: And what does the "flag" variable do exactly? i dont see it in any cycle

Comment: Can i just add an "else" and then "the sum of row in matrix are not equal"?